# How to convert custom routing table to main routing table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, amazon-vpc

How to convert custom routing table to main routing table in AWS, so that if we create new subnet in the VPC implicitly that new subnet will be associated with the custom routing table?

Answer (score 1):

Open VPC service => Open `Route Tables` in left side

Select `route table`, which you want => Select `Action` => `Set Main Route Table`